# Meaning of "pull up"

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

What's the meaning of *pull up*?

> Tried pulling up on my cell(video), wouldn't work. Will watch when I get home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Pulling up*** in this context means to load something from the Internet onto the phone.  Since the context you provided indicates a video, the person wished to watch a video on his or her phone, but was unable to load it.